# Case function scoring not summing correctly

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a case statement which scores interactions as below, my question relates to this line:
case when hits.eventInfo.eventAction CONTAINS "Basket Icon Click" then 5 else 0 end +

When run with a value of 5, 10, 15 it does not increase the score, if I set the value to 1000 then this does effect the score. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```html
select visitID, ROUND(SUM(Session_Score)/SUM(totals.hits),2) as Session_Score
from (
    select *,
      case when totals.pageviews > 2 then 5 else 0 end +
      case when totals.pageviews > 5 then 10 else 0 end +
      case when totals.pageviews > 10 then 20 else 0 end +
      case when totals.transactions > 0 then 100 else 0 end +
      case when hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS "Checkout" then 50 else 0 end +
      case when hits.page.pagePath CONTAINS "SignIn" then 30 else 0 end +
      case when hits.eventInfo.eventAction CONTAINS "Basket Icon Click" then 5 else 0 end +
      case when geoNetwork.country = "United Kingdom" then 1 else 0 end +
      case when hits.hour = 20 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when hits.hour = 21 then 1 else 0 end +
      case when hits.hour = 22 then 1 else 0 
      end as Session_Score
    from [tbl]
) scored

GROUP by visitID
order by Session_Score desc
```

Comment: It makes my head hurt to reason about what's happening in that query :) Can you try expressing it using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead? With legacy SQL, expressions over repeated fields tend to have weird/surprising semantics; in this case, `hits` is repeated.

Comment: Hi Elliot - i'm new to SQL and all the resources I found for BigQuery taught me Legacy - I've struggled to find anywhere that explains how Standard is different and how I can write it! Could you take a shot at translating it?

Comment: The [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) is a good source for differences between the two. I might be able to try rewriting your query if I get a chance later, or perhaps someone else will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using ROUND(...). If you don't ROUND() the Session_Score, does it properly change?

Also, some guidance on how to rewrite to standardSql below. It's not a drop in replacement, but you really just need to change the `CONTAINS "foo"` to `LIKE "%foo%"`.  You may need to do some correlated cross joins if you have any repeated fields (I can't tell from your example).

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  tbl AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS visitID,
    10 AS pageviews,
    1 AS hits,
    "Checkout SignIn" AS pagePath,
    "Basket Icon Click" AS eventAction)
SELECT
  visitID,
  ROUND(SUM(Session_Score)/SUM(hits), 2) AS Session_Score
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE
      WHEN pageviews > 2 THEN 5
      ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN pageviews > 5 THEN 10
      ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN pageviews > 10 THEN 20
      ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN pagePath LIKE "%Checkout%" THEN 50
      ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN pagePath LIKE "%SignIn%" THEN 30
      ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN eventAction LIKE "%Basket Icon Click%" THEN 5
      ELSE 0
    END as Session_Score
  FROM
    tbl)
GROUP BY
  visitID
ORDER BY
  Session_score DESC
```